# Working with several time zone in Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-timezone

The application I am working on has as target users USA. And (as you may know) in USA there's more than one time zone. So I have some doubts:

- so how could I get the current time in server side based on the
  current user?
- And how could I store `DateTime` data to show the correct time for
  every user?
- How can I compare times (example: `user.event.created > datetime.now()`)? What timezone will `.now()` use?
- What TIME_ZONE should I set in `settings.py` file.

This is for an API, to grab user's timezone via JS is not an option. I get the current user via TokenAuthentication.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UTC` for `settings.py` and grab their timezone offset from Javascript:

```
var utcOffset = -((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()) / 60;
```

e.g. for Los Angeles right now `utcOffset == -7`

Unfortunately this doesn't account for Daylight Savings Time changes later (offset changes to `-8`), so you may have to figure that out at the time of retrieval in order to get `Pacific/Los_Angeles`. Otherwise you could always just ask the user in a signup form if it's important for your business.

EDIT: Since you're using an API, you could also try using the [IPInfoDB API](http://ipinfodb.com/) to geolocate based on client IP address. It's not always completely accurate, but almost always enough to get the correct timezone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I may have to ask the user. I had to point in answer I am working in an API, so I can't use JS to get user's time zone.

Comment: @Gocht I edited my answer with another possible solution since you're using an API.

Comment: So you recommend store the user timezone? or get it everytime user access to the API. I edited the question with one more doubt.

Comment: You need to figure that out yourself based on your business model. I've been on a project where we stored the timezone because we needed to create graphs and data tables and ensure they remained consistent. I could see use cases where you'd want to collect it every time (though I'd shy away from this), but I don't know your business.

Comment: Let tell you a little please. I have user `type1` and `type2`, users `type1` create `events` and users `type2` must see events in their location area (based in a map). Currently I store automatic `created` using `auto_now`, but it store the server's ` now` but user can set the `event_date`, now I need to do some stuff with event passed its date, that's why I need compare times. User will set `event_date` according his timezone, which could be different from server timezone or even users `type2` users

Comment: Yeah, it's too complex to go over completely in an SO comment thread. The two most annoying things to deal with in programming are language/encodings and time/timezones, so there's no avoiding critical thinking, sweat, and frustration. Good luck and thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use datetime.now(), use the now() function in the timezone module instead.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

Django will figure out which timezone you are in and compare them accordingly.

```
user.event.created > timezone.now()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I guess `timezone.now()` get the timezone in `settings.py` file. But in some cases, user will have a different timezone.

Comment: by default it uses the timezone in the setting, but if you have user specific timezone you can activate timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname)). Look at the TimezoneMiddleware in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to always store unix timestamps in the database. You can generate with `time.time()` . That means your model should have a Floatfield (or even a BigIntegerField depending on the accuracy needed).

Your template should display the numeric value as it is. Then you need a tiny bit of javascript to convert that unix timestamp to a date time.

```
new Date(unix_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The users of your webapp may be in different time zones, so the conversion to an appropriate time zone is necessary. You can create a middleware and use [activate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#s-default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) function to set the appropriate time zone. You can get the client-side timezone by doing an ajax api call to **[Free IP Geolocation API](https://freegeoip.app/)** in your landing page and the timezone value can be saved in a cookie variable which can be later accessed in the middleware.

**landingpage.html**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://freegeoip.app/json/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            document.cookie = 'timezone=' + data['time_zone'] + '; path=/';
        }
      });
</script>
```

**middleware.py**

```
import pytz
import requests

from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    
    tzname = request.COOKIES.get('timezone')
    if tzname:
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
    else:
        timezone.deactivate()
    return self.get_response(request)
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [      ........
            'projectname.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
```

]